# Bootstrap CSS is overriding KML CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a pop-up box that displays once my Google Map is opened using Bootstrap code. Can be found here: http://userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~catam/carrie2.html

The Bootstrap pop-up box is referencing an external style sheet in my HTML, found here:  http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

My problem, is that the Bootstrap CSS is overriding the stylization of my tables in the info windows of my KML layers. I tried naming the style id in the KML layers as "shp2kml" which successfully stylizes the tables to show in Google Earth but once I publish the KML layer and reference it in my HTML, the style is overridden by the Bootstrap CSS.

The KML layer is written like so in my code of the map :

```
//layer 5 Schools
        layers [5] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkckJvUlEzS0VuREU&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: false});
```

Ideally, I want both the Bootstrap code to work, and have my info windows stylized as I originally had before the Bootstrap code: http://userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~catam/collab3.html

Comment: put your KML css below the bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are loading your Bootsrap CSS before your KML CSS and before the KML script is being called.